# Issues with Google or Facebook Federated IdP

Tags: facebook, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to set up Google and Facebook federated IdP. For Facebook we tried using Oauth2 as well as Facebook configuration. From the SP, we are redirected to Facebook, authenticate with Facebook, and on continuing, it throws IdentityException "Error when reading claim values for generating SAML Response
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException".

[2015-12-09 16:47:11,424] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in Authentication Framework
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils.getFederatedSubjectFromClaims(Lorg/wso2/carbon/identity/application/common/model/IdentityProvider;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.buildClaims(FacebookAuthenticator.java:299)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(FacebookAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:367)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handleResponse(DefaultStepHandler.java:348)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSeque
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticat
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.ja
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: `Exception in Authentication Framework java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. This might be a version error.